# how to implement onchange dynamically in the select tag

Tags: javascript, select, dynamic

this is a  part of my code were i am dynamically creating select statement and in the loop generating option for the select statement.

```
var el_s = document.createElement('select');        
     for(var i=0;i<32;i++)
     {
       var j = i;
       j = document.createElement('option');
       j.text=i;
       j.name="day";
       el_s.appendChild(j);
      }
```

in the above code i want  2 things
    1.how to set **"value" attribute** to the select statement
    2.how to fetch selected value on **event "onchange"**

ie, when a user chooses a value from the drop down the value stored .

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var el_s = document.createElement('select');
el_s.setAttribute('id','el_s');
 for(var i=0;i<32;i++)
 {

   var  j = document.createElement('option');
   j.text=i;
   j.name="day";
   j.setAttribute("value",i);
   el_s.appendChild(j);

 }
 el_s.setAttribute("onchange", "myFunc()");
 body.appendChild(el_s); // or wherever you want
```

To fetch the value of selected element
you can do

```
pName = document.getElementById('el_s');
var value = pName.options[pName.selectedIndex].value;
```